# Access Azure Files Share from WebAppService

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

We are currently moving an old ASP.net web application from a hosted server IIS7 to Azure.

In the current setup the site is accessing a File Server using an UNC path to a shared folder on the file server.

```
\\file-server\files-client
```

We do, for now, not want to change this approach since it will substantially complicate the moving process.

We have set up an Azure Storage with File Service and a share in this called files-client

This can be access perfectly from a VM by setting up credentials and accessing it via

```
\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\files-client
```

But

We really would want to have this site run as a Web App Service since it gives us a number of advantages.

We have set up an App Service, have published the Web Application, and all is running great including DB access etc.

Unfortunately our luck runs out when the Web Application tries to access the file share using

```
\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\files-client\test.jpg
```

We get an access error:

```
Access to the path '\\storageaccount.file.core.windows.net\files-client\test.jpg' is denied.
```

This tells me that the App Service sees the share but is not authorized to access it.

I know that we somehow has to grant the App Service access to this storage, but searching the net intensively tells me that this cannot be done which I simply cannot understand, and hopefully I'm not looking in the right places.

Sp the question is: How do I set up the credentials in the App Service to have it access my Storage share?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Service sandbox explicitly does not allow access to the ports necessary for SMB protocol (137/138/139/445).

This article mentions it under Restricted Outgoing Ports: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

I was afraid of that, but why am I getting an Access Denied error and not a resource not found error if the ports are blocked ?